# Cannot resolve parameter in boolean node in Symfony config files

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a (private) bundle that expects boolean parameter:

```php
$rootNode
    ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
    ->children()
        ->booleanNode('property_cache_enabled')->defaultTrue()->end()
    ->end()
```

When I want it to resolve to `kernel.debug` it throws the exception:

> Invalid type for path "rvlt_digital_symfony_api.property_cache_enabled". Expected boolean, but got string.

This is the relevant part of configuration:

```
rvlt_digital_symfony_api:
  property_cache_enabled: '%kernel.debug%'
```

How can this be solved? When I searched for this issue I only found stuff related to environment variables casting; which didn't help as this is not an environment variable.

Comment: Interesting.  Don't have time to make a test case but I think if your use defaultValue('%kernel.debug%') in your config tree then you will get the desired result.

Comment: And if you look at the framework bundle's Configuration you can see that the debug flag is injected into the constructor.  And then various nodes use defaultValue($this->debug)

Comment: @Cerad thanks, but that doesn't solve it, the true value is a correct default, I need it to resolve from the config. Currently I worked around it by creating a separate config in dev directory that has `true` while the default config has `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the value of `%kernel.debug%` to configure your module directly, without having to set explicit configuration for that value.

Change your configuration class so it goes:

```php
class ApplicationConfiguration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    private $debug;

    public function  __construct($debug)
    {
        $this->debug = (bool) $debug;
    }

    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('rvlt_digital_symfony_api');

        $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
            ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
            ->children()
                ->booleanNode('property_cache_enabled')->defaultValue($this->debug)->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

And your extension class so that when configuration is instantiated, the value for `%kernel.debug%` is read from the container and injected into the configuration instance:

```php
class ApplicationExtension extends Extension
{
     public function getConfiguration(array $config, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        return new Configuration($container->getParameter('kernel.debug'));
    }
}
```

This way, if you do not set up the configuration for `rvlt_digital_symfony_api.property_cache_enabled` it simply matches the app's `%kernel.debug%` setting, which is what you wanted in the first place. (You can still configure this value and override the default, though).

This use case is explicitly talked about in the docs here: [Using Parameters within a Dependency Injection Class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/using_parameters_in_dic.html)

Comment: That's not a solution to me, the default needs to be true, but on my development machine I want it to be based on kernel.debug parameter.

Comment: Not entirely sure why can't you accomplish that with this code. Just use a different configuration for `dev` and `prod`.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing but I find it strange that you need to create separate config just to resolve a parameter.